# Difference between “is” and “it is” in a sentence

Tags: grammar

1. What is the difference between “is” and “it is” in a sentence?

Please make sure that the password *is* at least 8 characters long.
Please make sure that the password *it is* at least 8 characters long.

A boarding pass *is* required.
A boarding pass *it is* required.

*Is* raining today.
*It is* raining today.

The food *is* good.
The food *it is* good.

*Is* great.
*It is* great.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you give us more context and explanation? And can you give us example sentences? Your question is not entirely clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first, second, and fourth sample sentences, you already have a subject, *the password*, *a boarding pass* and *the food*, and therefore don't need to include an **it**. Although it may be more common to use in other languages, the **it** part is left out in English (I'm not sure if leaving it in is incorrect grammar, or just not done in practice).

However, if you add a comma after the subject, you can include **it**. The resulting sentence puts an added emphasis on the subject (though, this is quite uncommonly used):

> The food, it is good.

Picture someone saying that sentence: *The food `*pause*` it is **good**.*

Comment: "The food, it is good" is an example of **left dislocation**.

Comment: "The food, it is good" would be more of an _idiom_ (and still an unusual phrasing) than good English sentence structure. In all the other cases, adding a comma would be **bad** to some degree.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if I have understood your question correctly. However I'll try to answer.

In English verbs are normally used with the subject they refer to. This is because most verbs do not change their ending to adapt to a singular or plural subject. For example, we say *"you **are**"* both when we are talking to one person only or to a group of people, as much as we say *"I **have**"* and *"they **have**"*. Without a proper subject we would not be able to correctly understand the meaning of a verb.

The verb ***"is"*** refers to a third person singular but this is not enough to make a sentence correct and complete, so we use it in conjunction with either ***he***, ***she*** or ***it***.

Coming to the sentences you list, ***it*** is only required in the third sentence (***It*** *is raining today*) because in the other sets of examples there is a proper subject and adding *it* would be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The password, a boarding pass and the food are the subject of `is` in the given examples, so you do not need to add an extra subject `it`. 
In "it is raining", *it* is the subject so you cannot leave it out.

So in short, only in the phrase "it is raining"  do you use "it", in the other examples "it" should not be there.

Comment: For additional reading: [ELL questions about _raining_](http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A+%22raining%22).